# How to choose save device for downloads on Xbox Live

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-network, xbox-dashboard

When you start a download on Xbox Live from your console it will automatically download to the HDD(Hard drive). If there is no space on the drive, it allows you to choose a different storage device, providing there is space.

So, where's the option to download to USB from the beginning?

Basically, I have a game on my USB. Inserting the USB brings up the game as a trial. So, I have to re-download the game from the marketplace. Although, instead of ipdating the USB, it will download to the HDD. If I place another download ahead of it, it should give me an option to download to a different device if there's space. Or if there isn't enough space on the HDD it will give me an option. So, there isn't an option to select a device first. Meaning, I have to clear space on the HDD, copy to the HDD from the USB, click download again. It will go from 1%-100% immediatly. Copy back to USB.

Comment: Please add that information to your question, not in a comment. Use the edit button.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I'm figuring now, that if you plug the USB in after the Xbox is on. Things should run smoother. Shall check in the waking hours.